# Python pandas: remove everything before a delimiter in a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frames which contain e.g.:

```
524_004_SoEx
67hh_004_Mont
yh88_004_BurS
1243gt_004_Pogr_st
```

I need to remove everything (and including) the two *004* so that I end up with:

```
SoEx
Mont
BurS
Pogr_st
```

I tried str.split without success. what would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
out = df['col'].str.extract(r'004_(.*)', expand=False)
print (out)
0       SoEx
1       Mont
2       BurS
3    Pogr_st
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Or [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
out = df['col'].str.split('004_').str[-1]
print (out)
0       SoEx
1       Mont
2       BurS
3    Pogr_st
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the leading part with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['your_col'] = df['your_col'].str.replace('.*004_', '', regex=True)
```

Or [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['your_col'] = df['your_col'].str.extract('004_(.*)', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
  your_col
0     SoEx
1     Mont
2     BurS
3  Pogr_st
```

The difference between the two approaches lies in the case in which you don't have `004_`, for instance:

```
             your_col
0        524_004_SoEx
1       67hh_004_Mont
2       yh88_004_BurS
3  1243gt_004_Pogr_st
4      Something_else
```

`replace` and `extract` will yield:

```
             your_col         replace  extract
0        524_004_SoEx            SoEx     SoEx
1       67hh_004_Mont            Mont     Mont
2       yh88_004_BurS            BurS     BurS
3  1243gt_004_Pogr_st         Pogr_st  Pogr_st
4      Something_else  Something_else      NaN   # difference
```